# Full screen popup with scrollview

Tags: c#, wpf, win-universal-app

I am making a windows universal app.

I want to create a popup that will fill the screen, and scroll if the content in the popup is larger than the screen.

```
Popup testPopup = new Popup();

StackPanel testStackPanel = new StackPanel();

ScrollViewer testScrollViewer = new ScrollViewer();
testScrollViewer.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green);
testScrollViewer.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star).Value; //this sets the height to one pixel     instead of filling the screen.

Button testPopupButton = new Button();
testPopupButton.Content = "click";
testPopupButton.Click += delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    testPopup.IsOpen = true;
};

Button closePopupButton = new Button();
closePopupButton.Content = "close";
closePopupButton.Click += delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    testPopup.IsOpen = false;
};

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Content = i;

    testStackPanel.Children.Add(b);
}

testStackPanel.Children.Add(closePopupButton);

testPopup.Child = testScrollViewer;
testScrollViewer.Content = testStackPanel;
ContentRoot.Children.Add(testPopupButton);
ContentRoot.Children.Add(testPopup);
```

I create a popup with it's child set to a scrollViewer, and the scrollViewers content is a stackPanel that is taller than the screen height.

If I manually set the height of the popup, it works as intended. My problem is getting the popups height and width to fill the screen. Leaving the height alone makes the height the size of the content, which goes off screen and doesn't scroll.

Comment: how about using a window with windowstyle as none and windowstate as maximized.

Comment: *If I manually set the height of the popup, it works as intended*... then why don't you just do that?

Comment: @pushpraj I am creating a Windows Universal App, I don't have a window class.

Answer (score 2):

You could set Width and Height using the System.Windows.SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth and System.Windows.SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight properties in the constructor of the window like so:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    popup.Width = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth;
    popup.Height = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
}
```

This is if you want to use this approach. However, @pushpraj recommends the best means of accomplishing your requirement.

Comment: I am creating a windows universal app, there is no SystemParameters

Comment: Give [this](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2014/06/building-multi-resolution-popups-in.html) a shot then. If you want full screen, you could just pass the ConverterParameter the value 100.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, BaseValueConverter does not exists. also I need to set the width and height in c# not xaml.